# How to set an array of C strings on an out-parameter of a Rust FFI function?

Tags: c, arrays, rust, ffi

I would like create a Rust FFI function that takes an out-parameter for arrays, analogous to this C function:

```c
size_t arr_out_c(char ***out) {
    char *msg = "the quick brown fox";
    size_t STR_LEN = strlen(msg) +1;
    size_t count = 3;
    char** arr = calloc( count,  sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arr[i] = calloc(STR_LEN,  sizeof(char));
        strncpy(arr[i], msg, STR_LEN * sizeof(char));
    }
    *out = arr;
    return count;
}
```

Usage:

```c
char** test;
size_t count = arr_out_c(&test);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("item: %s", test[i]);
}
```

I've gotten close with this:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn arr_out_rust(strings_out: *mut *mut *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char) -> usize {
    unsafe {
        let s1 = ::std::ffi::CString::new("the quick brown fox").unwrap();
        let s2 = ::std::ffi::CString::new("the quick brown fox").unwrap();
        let mut strs = vec![s1, s2];
        let len = strs.len();

        let mut boxed_slice = strs.into_boxed_slice();
        *strings_out = boxed_slice.as_mut_ptr() as *mut *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char;
        mem::forget(boxed_slice);
        len
    }
}
```

It works for the first item in the array, attempting to access the 2nd item results in a SEGV.   Perhaps the `CString`s are not getting packed in a contiguous block of memory... or maybe the `len` data in `slice` is part of that memory?

Also, to free this memory, can I just call the C `free` function on it in C space, or do I need to send it back into Rust space and call `drop`?

```c
char** test;
size_t count = arr_out_rust(&test);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("item: %s", test[i]);
}
```

will print a single `the quick brown fox`, then crash.

---

While this question has some similarities to questions asking about **returning** strings to C, it's pretty unique in that it is asking about out-bound pointers in FFI.  Marking it as a duplicate and closing it would go against the spirit of Stack Overflow as a repository of unique answers.

Comment: while the answer was similar, the question was not anywhere close to being the same.

Comment: Does that mean that you read the linked duplicates and solved your problem? That you cannot return a `CString` across the FFI boundary?

Comment: For beginner FFI questions, I highly recommend reading my [Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/).

Comment: Your general method of returning the array is just fine, therefore any answer to the question you *asked* would be "do exactly what you are doing". You didn't reduce your question enough to the core of the problem — returning `CString` instead of `* const c_char`. And yes, you always have to free Rust allocations back in Rust land. You will need to reconstitute the `Vec` and then let it drop.